# Does pandas != 'a value' return NaNs?

Tags: python, pandas, comparison, nan

When I use 
`x['test'] = df['a_variable'].str.contains('some string')`
I get-

```
True
NaN
NaN
True
NaN
```

If I use
`x[x['test'] != True]`
Should I receive back the rows with value NaN?

Thanks.

Comment: When I run that statement I receive the rows back with NaN. In general with Pandas I would expect to need to explicitly include NaNs in a statement like `NaNs.include = True`.

Comment: @VigneshKalai I suggested an edit. You could have as well accepted that. The question is still badly formatted.

Comment: From which module is *contains*?

Comment: What is not clear? My question is whether you would expect `x[x['test'] != True]` to return any value which is NaN? I am not sure how to make this clearer so would appreciate you explaining why it is not clear instead of just criticism.

Comment: guidot, I think it is pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.contains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is expected behaviour:

```
In [3]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'some_string':['asdsa','some',np.NaN, 'string']})
df

Out[3]:
  some_string
0       asdsa
1        some
2         NaN
3      string

In [4]:
df['some_string'].str.contains('some')

Out[4]:
0    False
1     True
2      NaN
3    False
Name: some_string, dtype: object
```

Using the above as a mask:

```
In [13]:
df[df['some_string'].str.contains('some') != False]

Out[13]:
  some_string
1        some
2         NaN
```

So the above is expected behaviour.

If you specify the value for `NaN` values using [`na=value`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) then you can get whatever value you set as the returned value:

```
In [6]:
df['some_string'].str.contains('some', na=False)

Out[6]:
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: some_string, dtype: bool
```

The above becomes important as indexing with `NaN` values will result in a `KeyError`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes we would expect it to happen

**ex.)**

```
x=pd.DataFrame([True,NaN,True,NaN])
print x

    0
0   True
1   NaN
2   True
3   NaN

print x[x[0] != True]

    0
1   NaN
3   NaN
```

`x[x[0] != True]`  would return every thing where the value is not `True`

`Like wise`

```
print x[x[0] != False]

    0
0   True
1   NaN
2   True
3   NaN
```

Since equation says to return all value which are not `False`